# Flutter - FloatingActionButton in the center

Tags: dart, flutter, floating-action-button, center-align

Is it possible to make the `FloatingActionButton` in the centre instead of the right side?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'number.dart';
import 'keyboard.dart';

class ContaPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(
    body: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Number(),
        new Keyboard(),
      ],
    ),
    floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
      elevation: 0.0,
      child: new Icon(Icons.check),
      backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFE57373),
      onPressed: (){}
    )
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a `Center` widget or use a `crossAxisAlignment` of `CrossAxisAlignment.center` on your `Column`.

You should pick one part of your `Column` to be wrapped in a `Flexible` that will collapse to avoid overflow, or replace some or all of it with a `ListView` so users can scroll to see the parts that are hidden.

Comment: But where In floatingActionButton or in body?

Comment: I try in floatingActionButton propertie the new Center wrap the new FloatingActionButton, the button is approximately in the center of the screen, and not in the center at the bottom of the screen

Comment: Make it the last element of a Column. You can also use a crossAxisAlignment of CrossAxisAlignment.center on your Column instead

Comment: This answer is wrong! The `floatingActionButton` property of the `Scaffold()` widget is not in ANY way influenced by the `mainAxisAlignment` property of the `Column()` widget which is in the `body` property! Luckily... It would be very annoying if those two parts of the `Scaffold()` couldn't be managed separately.

Answer (score 173):

I don't know if this was added since this question was first answered, but there's now `floatingActionButtonLocation` property on the `Scaffold` class.

It would work like this in your original question:

```
class ContaPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(
    // ...

    floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
      // ...FloatingActionButton properties...
    ),

    // Here's the new attribute:

    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
  );
}
```

Also see the documentation:

- `Scaffold` class (search `floatingActionButtonLocation`): https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html
- ...and the `FloatingActionButtonLocation` class: https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButtonLocation-class.html

Comment: The provided links point to a site with an invalid certificate.

Answer (score 48):

With the new flutter API you do that very easily just change the `floatingActionButtonLocation` property in the Scaffold to

```
FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat
```

[image]

> Example :

```
return new Scaffold(
  floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation:    
      FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
  bottomNavigationBar: new BottomAppBar(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: new Row(...),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 26):

Use the Property **floatingActionButtonLocation** of **scaffold** class.

**floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,**

Full Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage()
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(child: Center(child: Text('Hello World')),),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.camera, color: Colors.white, size: 29,),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        tooltip: 'Capture Picture',
        elevation: 5,
        splashColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

[image: floatingActionButton center]

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
```

Use this property with floatingActionButtonLocation property in Scaffold.

[FloatingActionButton Flutter - More Details](https://androidride.com/floating-action-button-flutter-example/)

Answer (score 8):

You can use Container and Align widgets as below:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Center(

      ),
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100.0),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
            onPressed: _getPhoneAuthResult,
            icon: Icon(Icons.phone_android),
            label: Text("Authenticate using Phone"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Container(
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          hoverColor: Colors.black,
                          elevation: 10,
                          onPressed: () {},
                          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                          child: Icon(Icons.add,),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Here I used "Align" widget to make the FloatingActionButton center. [You can see it here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgF0h.png)

Answer (score 6):

after end of the floating action button widget, you can Use `floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,`

For Example

```
   import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  File _image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      title: "Camera App",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Camera App"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Center(
            child: _image == null
                ? Text('No image selected.')
                : Image.file(_image,
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          elevation: 50,
          hoverColor: Colors.red,
          autofocus: true,
          onPressed: () {
            imagepicker();
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
          tooltip: 'Pick Image',
        ),
         floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      ),
    );
  }

  Future imagepicker() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The above examples are great, but if you want to have full control over the exact location of the floating action button, you should wrap your FloatingActionButton widget with Align widget and use Alignment(x axis, y axis) to set the exact location.

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.8), 
//control the location by changing the numbers here to anything between 1 and -1
  child: FloatingActionButton()
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [`Scaffold.floatingActionButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/floatingActionButton.html) just asks for a `Widget`, you can wrap your [`FloatingActionButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html) with the standard classes for more control if the [`Scaffold.floatingActionButtonLocation`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/floatingActionButtonLocation.html) property isn't enough (which already gives you many standard [placements](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButtonLocation-class.html), that can also play nicely with your `appBar` or `bottomNavigationBar`).

[`Container`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) is a classic component, but a little overkill given that it combines a variety of widgets.

As others mentioned, [`Align`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) is handy when you want to position relative to the `Align` widget itself (which if unconstrained fills to its parent). It can take a variety of preset [`Alignment`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Alignment-class.html) constants, or use the `Alignment` constructor to specify your own relative position, e.g. `Alignment(0.0, 0.0)` represents the center of the rectangle, `(1,1)` the bottom right corner, and `(-1,-1)` the upper left. However, the parent of your FAB is influenced by the Scaffold's `floatingActionButtonLocation:`, so one way to help take it into account is by setting it to   `FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked`, which when used with `Align` lets you think about positioning relative to the screen's center.

But maybe you like the basic positioning provided by `floatingActionButtonLocation`, but just want to shift the FAB by a known number of logical pixels, e.g. to compensate for other widgets on the screen. In that case wrapping in a [`Padding`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html) with the appropriate `EdgeInsets` should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

By changing the logic to use crossAxisAlignment, the mainAxisAlignment and the Flexible the FloatingActionButton were centered at the bottom of the screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'number.dart';
import 'keyboard.dart';

class ContaPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(
    body: new Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,       
      children: <Widget>[
        new Number(),
        new Keyboard(),
        new Flexible(
          child: new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
            child: new FloatingActionButton(
              elevation: 0.0,
              child: new Icon(Icons.check),
              backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFE57373),
              onPressed: (){}
            )
          )         
        )
      ],
    ), 
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For more freedom of alignment and more than 2 FAB use Stack

```
Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Center(
            child: _image == null
                ? Text('No image selected.')
                : Image.file(_image,
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                ),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: new FloatingActionButton(
              child: const Icon(Icons.skip_previous),
              onPressed: () {
              }),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: new FloatingActionButton(
              child: const Icon(Icons.skip_next),
              onPressed: () {
              }),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code, now the button is in the bottom center but I do not know if it will always stay in the bottom, regardless of the size of the screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'number.dart';
import 'keyboard.dart';

class ContaPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(
    body: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Number(),
        new Keyboard(),
        new Stack(
          alignment: new FractionalOffset(0.5, 1.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            new FloatingActionButton(
              elevation: 0.0,
              child: new Icon(Icons.check),
              backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFE57373),
              onPressed: (){}
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    ), 
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your design simply you can use **persistentFooterButtons** which accepts a list of widgets as children.

just like here for an example:

```
persistentFooterButtons: [
              new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: FloatingActionButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => InstallationPage()),);
                        },
                        child: new Icon(Icons.add, color: SysColors.ICON_COLOR, size: 34.w,),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              )
            ],
```