# Centering the extended FAB

Tags: dart, flutter

[image: Extended FAB]

How would you center the extended FAB provided in Flutter like the Material design spec?

Here the extended FAB is right aligned:

```
new Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onTap: () => {},
        label: new Text('See all results')
    }
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is set the `floatingActionButtonLocation` property on `Scaffold`

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: ...       
      body: ...
      floatingActionButton: MyFloatingActionButton(),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat
    );
  }

class MyFloatingActionButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FloatingActionButton.extended(
          icon: Icon(Icons.plus_one),
          onPressed: () => {},
          label: new Text('See all results'));
  }
}
```

Just note this is a duplicate of the question: [Flutter - FloatingActionButton in the center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44713501/flutter-floatingactionbutton-in-the-center?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)