# How can I move floating action button to the left side of the Screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, floating-action-button

By default floating action button is at the right side of the screen. I know about the `floatingActionButtonLocation` and its properties like `endDocked`, `startDocked`, `centerDocked`, but none of them helped me in moving it to the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically suggested by @E.Bradford in the comment above, but I wanted to provide some code, if needed. You can place the FloatingActionButton pretty much anywhere you want by stacking it into a positioned widget.

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Placeholder(),
    Positioned(
      left: 40,
      bottom: 40,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can just add into your Scaffold the named constructor:

`floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.startFloat`

or

`floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.startDocked`

Take the getting started app for example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    //##########################################################################
       floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.startFloat,
    //##########################################################################
/*
or

`floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.startDocked` 
*/
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe this previously provided answer provides the closest "Easy to Implement" set of options to your problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49761700/10768398

The answer basically says to use something similar to the following on your Scaffold component of your Widget tree:

```
, floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat
```

Based on the descriptions of the options it doesn't look like there is an align to the left.

Also take a look at the available options here:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButtonLocation-class.html

Comment: ya, I saw it. But it suggests for how to implement a floating action button on Center. And I want it to left side of the screen. But thanks for respond.

Comment: I added a bit to the answer, I don't think there is an align left option

Comment: Yes Sir, I just noticed your edit. I totally agree that by default there is not a left alignment option.

Comment: Just a thought, but would a Stack object (with an array of widgets In the stack) and with one of the children having a Positioned widget (your desired button)  work in your case?

Comment: I didn't try it yet. But as you suggest I'll try it as well.

Comment: It might qualify as a solution if you do not require scrolling on that particular screen.   Scrolling would scroll the button completely off the screen.

Answer (score 6):

This will place your FAB in the lower lefthand corner:

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.startDocked,
      floatingActionButton:
          FloatingActionButton(heroTag: null, onPressed: () {}),
   );
```

See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButtonLocation/startDocked-constant.html

Comment: Is there a way to add padding or a margin to the docked button so it's not as close to the edge of the screen?

Answer (score 3):

I used following code to make the floatingActionButton on left side by using padding on right side of FAB.

```
floatingActionButton: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 275.0),
    child: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(
        Icons.add,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      onPressed: (){},
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: I suggest to avoid this technique as you have different screen sizes and it the feeling will be different across devices.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your `floatingActionButton` with `Row()` and give `crossAxisAlignment` to center:

```
floatingActionButton: Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:25.0),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Add your onPressed code here!
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.message,color: Colors.white,),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
floatingActionButton: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: FloatingActionButton(

              onPressed: (){},
            ),
          ),
```