# How to center FloatingActionButton horizontally in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to center the `FloatingActionButton` horizontally on the screen but i don't seem to find any resource on how to do it..
This is my flutter code..

```
  void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Home()
));

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My App'),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown[700],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Add your onPressed code here!
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown[700],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white70
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44713501/flutter-floatingactionbutton-in-the-center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `Scaffold`:

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat
```

Comment: @ZulfiqarAli Your Welcome... Also you can accept the answer if it helped you so others could use it too

Comment: This is the right answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
floatingActionButton: Center(
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Add your onPressed code here!
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            backgroundColor: Colors.brown[700],
          ),
        ),
```

Result

[image: Result]

Comment: I knew how to do this but this way the `FloatingActionButton` gets centered both vertically and horizontally, i just wanted to center it horizontally downwards, `floatingActionButtonLocation` property worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

So this is the floatingActionButton property of the Scaffold.
You could put him into the body and then use a Center, or Column or Row widget to center it.
Otherwise, just wrap the FloatingActionButton in a Row with mainaxisalignment: MainaxisAlignment.center.
You can assign many widgets to the floatingActionButton property of the scaffold, not only FloatingActionButtons.
Hope this helps.

Edit: it would then look like this:

```
Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: Row(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
         children: [
             FloatingActionButton()
          ],
    ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try this out too.